# Bloat effect for image

Tags: php, python, node.js

Is there any way to make the bloat effect for image? Not necessarily from the center.

Any solution in Python/Node.js/PHP. Google did not return results

Example: 
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwziQ.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to shell out to ImageMagick: http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/spherize/index.php

Comment: The reference from kmoser is my bash unix ImageMagick shell script, which would likely do what you want. But you could also use -distort barrel from ImageMagick or create a custom displacement map. See https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#barrel and https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/mapping/#displace_2d

Comment: Might be able to do this in PHP by following Example 12 on this page: http://phpimagick.com/Imagick/distortImage